# Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Сижу, значит, делаю курсач, а тут
"Индекс находился вне границ массива".
Вот кусок кода, где налажал?

---

...

```
static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("try.txt", Encoding.Default);
             string n1;
            int u;
            int m1, ch1;
            double p1; 
            string[] str;
            Work worker = new Work();
            List<Work> lst = new List<Work>();
            while ((n1 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                str = n1.Split('/');
                m1 = int.Parse(str[2]); // Вот тут 
                ch1 = int.Parse(str[7]); 
                p1 = double.Parse(str[10]);
                lst.Add(new Work(str[0], str[1], m1, str[3], str[4], str[5], str[6], ch1, str[8], str[9], p1));

            }
```

### ...

В текстовом файле:

Иванов И.И. / Печенье/ 20000/ 03.03.1950/ 05.06.2014/ ХОлОСТ/ М / 0 / 05.06.2014/05.06.2014/3

Петров А.А/ Кексы/ 20000/ 04.04.1960/ 05.06.2014/ ХОлОСТ/ М / 0 / 05.06.2014/05.06.2014/3

Comment: Смотрите дебагером, что лежит в n1. Вероятно, файл всё-таки не такой.

Comment: @ssantonov, выводите в консоль n1, я подозреваю, у вас просто попадается пустая строка, которую, соответственно, нельзя разбить символом "/".

Answer (score 4):

Всё правильно. Вы вот пишете:

```
str = n1.Split('/');
m1 = int.Parse(str[2]); // Вот тут
```

А кто вам дал гарантию, что в `str` не менее трёх элементов? Никто. Вот оно и вылетает.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо "VladD" помог правильно пересмотреть код, он правильный, но не рассчитанный на то что в файле может быть пустая строка между строками, вот она и дает ошибку. -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Вывод, у вас пустой массив без дынных, и сразу после него в строке m1 = int.Parse(str[2]); ошибка потому что там ничего нет.

Comment: > Как вы умудрились создать массив без указания его размерности - `string[] str`

А вы C# с C++ не спутали случайно? (А ещё вы путаете размер с размерностью.)

Comment: Может быть, сонный немного, но даже в ++ нельзя делать так -  str = n1.Split('/'); если str является массивом.
и если это c++ то что это - List<Work> lst = new List<Work>(); это C# кокраз этот тег и прикреплен к вопросу.

Comment: Угу, в C++ нельзя, а в C# наоборот можно. В C# массивы являются ссылочными типами.

Дело в том, что вы пишете, будто бы нельзя создать массив синтаксисом `string[] str;`. Но это верно лишь для C++, а вопрос о C#.

---
Повторюсь. В C++ конструкция

    string[] str;

действительно не разрешена, так как размер массива неизвестен. В C# такая же конструкция допустима, так как объявляет не массив, а лишь ссылку на него.

---
Пруф того, что можно в C#: http://ideone.com/ybilqx

Ваш ход.

Comment: НО ДАЖЕ в ++ нельзя делать так - str = n1.Split('/'); ровно как в C#

В шарпе вы получите исчерпывающий ответ от студии что неявное преобразование из string в string[] невозможно.

Comment: да но где у него в коде инициализация массива, так как без этого нельзя
я там не увидел - str = new string[10];//
Хорошо согласен, виноват что не проверил, но все же, его код не работает

--Как правило, такой вопрос просит не найти ошибку а решить задачу, меея смутило что он неявно записывает в массив данные, а потом пытается их получить явно указывая индекс, но в таком случае нет никакой гарантии что и далее где он указывает индексы тоже что-то есть, до них просто очередь не дошла.

Comment: @denyardv: инициализация не нужна. Смотрите пример по ссылке на ideone. Заметьте, что компилятор ideone его скомпилировал и даже выполнил.

---
(Тут лимит на количество комментариев, объединил старые.)

Comment: "Пруф того, что можно в C#: http://ideone.com/ybilqx

Ваш ход."

public static void Main()
{
string n1 = "a/b/c/d";
string[] str;
str = n1.Split('/');
foreach (string s in str)
Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Согласен, неправ, но вы разрезали строку и вложили ее в массив без цикла, и потом вывели в цикле, перебрав его, но все делалось неявно, а в коде вопроса, все совершенно не так, может потому я и запутался.
Спасибо.

Comment: Угу. Вывод тут лишь для иллюстрации, что всё работает правильно, про существу он не нужен.

---
Так и есть, до остальных индексов код просто не успел дойти, так как вылетел. Скорее всего, на входе встретилась пустая строка.